# Unable to connect to deepstream server from website over HTTPS

Tags: websocket, socket.io, deepstream.io

As the title mentions, I am unable to connect to deepstream server from a website which is served over HTTPS. I am able to connect it through local server though.

Initially I was getting following error:

`deepstream.min.js:3 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://<deepstream-domain>:6020/deepstream'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.`

After getting this error, I changed the connection string to `wss://<deepstream-domain>`.

But this throws following error:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://<deepstream-domain>:6020/deepstream' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
{"isTrusted":true}`

Any idea how to solve this? Do I have to setup an SSL certificate in the deepstream server as well?

Comment: `example.com` is on nginx or what? You should route it through the same and then it would work. You will terminate the SSL at server and the forward it to `<deepstream-domain>:6020`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem by adding an SSL certificate to the domain and providing the SSL keys path in deepstream `config.yml` file.